# Deja-Dup: Upgrading to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, backup, deja-dup

I'm still running 12.04, waiting for the automatic upgrade to show up in the update manager.

I have a Data partition different from my Ubuntu home, where I keep mainly all my work and important documents. This is being backed up by Deja-Dup on an external hard-drive.

If I upgrade to 14.04, will I be able to "resume" these backups, knowing that the Data partition and hard-drive won't be affected by the upgrade? I would expect so, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: please visit these websites . you will get the solution for your problem [How to Back Up Ubuntu the Easy Way with Déjà Dup](http://www.howtogeek.com/108869/how-to-back-up-ubuntu-the-easy-way-with-dj-dup/) [DejaDup-HowItWorks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/HowItWorks)

Comment: Yes, you should be able to continue backing as normal.